# How to show and use radio button on ag-grid?

Tags: angular, radio-button, ag-grid

I am learning ag-grid and tried following code to show checkbox in my application.

In app.component.html:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  style:"width: 500px; height: 500px;"
  class: "ag-theme-balham"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  rowSelection="multiple"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [gridReady]="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

In AppComponent.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('agGrid')
  agGrid: AgGridNg2;
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
  gridOptions: GridOptions;

  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make', checkboxSelection: true}, 
    {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'}
    {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}, 
  ];
  rowData: [
    {make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000},
    {make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000},
    {make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000}
  ];

  onGridReady() {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  }
}
```

I wanted to show radio button instead of checkbox.

Comment: Check my answer, with a working example https://stackoverflow.com/a/73917289/16456741

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For handing `visual` part, you need to create custom
>   [`cellRenderer`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/)
>
> For handling `edit` stuff, you should create custom [`cellEditor`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/)

So, for custom `components`, you need to create `.html` file for visual things and `.ts` for logic handling.

simple `.html` for radio buttons:

```
<div class="radio-container">
    <input type="radio" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (change)="stopEdit()">
    <input type="radio" [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (change)="stopEdit()">
    <input type="radio" [value]="3" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (change)="stopEdit()">
</div>
```

and on `.ts` you must handle `ICellEditorComp` `functions`:

1. `agInit` - for initialization and binding existing value to your model
2. `isPopup` - would it be a `popup` window or inside the cell
3. `getValue` - this `function` will return the value **after** `stopEditing` api-function execution

simple `.ts`

```
private params: any;
public radioValue: number;

agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.radioValue = params.value;
}

getValue(): any {
    return this.radioValue;
}

isPopup(): boolean {
    return true;
}

stopEdit() {
  alert(`Value changed to: ${this.radioValue}`);
  this.params.api.stopEditing();
}
```

Don't forget, that custom `components` should be included to `frameworkComponents` inside `gridOptions` or as `[frameworkComponents]` html `ag-grid` property.

Worked [plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/pazZGMdVOXRSY3VFECDZ)

> Update: `row-selection` via `radio-button` inside `cellRenderer`

```
NOT SELECTED
<input type="radio" [(checked)]="!params.node.selected"  (change)="handleChange()">
SELECTED
<input type="radio" [(checked)]="params.node.selected" (change)="handleChange()">
{{params.value}}

handleChange() {
  this.params.node.setSelected(!this.params.node.selected)
}
```

Also - keep in mind that in this case, we don't need to use `editor`, logic could be handled via `renderer` only

Worked [plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/ozXiHV)

Comment: Hi, I actually wanted to have radio button in column like that of checkbox (which appears when "checkboxSelection:true") and select entire row when radio button is selected.

Comment: you can't customize exactly `checkboxSelection` feature, you can try to create own `headerComponent` and `cellRendererComponent` - but it would be complex task

Comment: Can we have a column with radio buttons and select row by selecting the radio button? I do not want to edit checkboxSelection feature. Instead I will not show checkbox and show radio button column.

Comment: In this approach, when I select one radio Button, entire radio buttons are being selected. I am not able to select individual radio buttons at time.

Comment: Thank you for updating post. But, I wanted single radio button per row. When user click of individual radio button, then that row should be selected. When another row with radio button is selected, new row gets selected. This is exact scenario when we have checkbox in ag-grid with row-selection mode of single. I wanted radio-button in place of checkbox with similar functionality.

Comment: Selected row index can be obtained from params.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to select the radio button on rowSelection?  I am having issues with this here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918954/make-aggrid-radio-button-cellrenderer-selected-on-row-click

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: In columnDefs: `{checkboxSelection: false}` // Add this to your object

Step 2: Add this to the same object where you added `checkboxSelection`

```js
cellRenderer: function cellTitle(params) {
  let cellValue = '<div class="ngSelectionCell"><input name="selected" type="radio"></div>';
  return cellValue;
},
```

Step 3: Add this code to your local css file:

```css
.ag-body {
  .ag-row {
    .ag-cell {
      input[type=checkbox]:checked:after, 
      input[type=radio]:checked:after {
        display: none;
       }
      input[type=checkbox]:after, input[type=radio]:after {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't work for rowSelection.  Is it possible to click anywhere on the row and make the radio button selected?

Comment: @s89_ are you able to achieve it radio selection on click of row (anywhere)?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the rowSelection property in your AppComponent.ts. just change your attribute from multiple to single. In this way the checkbox will behave like a radio button.

```
rowSelection: 'single',
```

Comment: This is one approach. I tried creating custom cell component. With that approach, when I am selecting a row with radio button, other radio buttons also got selected. We can customize row.

Comment: I do not seem to understand your question. Please ellaborate.

Comment: What if I want the checkbox to look like a radio button?

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to set some grid properties. If single row selection is needed (which is the normal behavior for a radio button) set `rowSelection='single'`.
Also if you want to select the row only when clicking the checkbox add this property `suppressRowClickSelection=true`

Next, Ag grid needs to show a checkbox, that we will later turn into radio button. So this is needed inside the proper column definition: `checkboxSelection: true`

And then add the following CSS, to change the icon used for the checkbox to be a radio button icon:

```
.ag-checkbox-input-wrapper::after {
    content: '\f124'
}
    
.ag-checkbox-input-wrapper.ag-checked::after {
    content: '\f125';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you create a custom render:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input name="radio" type="radio" [checked]="isChecked" (click)="onClick()">
</div>
```

TS:

```
export class SelectionRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  params: any;
  row: any;
    
  get isChecked(): boolean {
  //if you need it
  }

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.row = this.params.data;
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  onClick(): void {
    //trigger subscription
  }
}
```

AgGridConfiguration:

```
initializeGridColumns(): Array<ColDef > {
      const columnDefinitions = new Array<ColDef>();
      columnDefinitions.push(new UpdateSelectionColumn().create());
      columnDefinitions.push(
          { headerName: 'First Name', field: 'FirstName', width: 300},
      ....
      return columnDefinitions;
  }

export class UpdateSelectionColumn {    
  create(): ColDef {
      return {
          headerName: '',
          field: '',
          cellRendererFramework: SelectionRendererComponent
      };
  }
}
```