# How to Group radio button which are in different rows of ag-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, ag-grid, radio-group

I'm creating a grid with multiple rows and inserting a radio button to each row as shown in below snapshot

[image]

The code snippet for the column definition of Radio button is as below,

```
columnDefs: [{
                headerName: '',
                field: '',
                tooltipField: '',
                suppressMenu: false,
                suppressFilter: true,
                suppressMovable: true,
                suppressResize: true,
                width: 200,
                cellRendererFramework: this.ButtonCellRenderer
               }]



 ButtonCellRenderer = (params) => {
      return (
        <div style={{margin: 'auto', width: '100%', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
          <div style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
            <RadioButtonGroup
              name={params.data.bit_rate}
              defaultSelected={this.state.selectedRadioButton}
              debugger //eslint-disable-line
              onChange={handleSelectionChange}
              labelPosition={this.state.labelPosition}
            >
              <RadioButton label='' value='true' enabled='true' />
            </RadioButtonGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

The issue I'm facing here is I'm not able to group the radio button into single RadioGroup hence I'm not achieving the mutual exclusive.
Can you please suggest how to make it mutual exclusive .

Comment: If possible can you share your radio button example in a plunkr.I am also trying radio buttons in ag-grid.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it programmatically by giving all your input/radio elements a `name` attribute and loop on all elements with the same name:

```
handleClick = () => {
        const elems = document.getElementsByName("rad");
        let selected;
        for(let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            if(elems[i].checked) {
                selected = elems[i].value;
            }
        }
        console.log(selected);
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <input type={"radio"} name={"rad"} defaultChecked={true} value={'radio1'} onClick={this.handleClick}/> radio1 <br/>
                <input type={"radio"} name={"rad"} value={'radio2'} onClick={this.handleClick}/> radio2
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the **name** and **id** attributes of the input tag unique and dynamic so that each ag-grid cell will create a unique pair

[Plunker Example link: ag-grid radio component](https://plnkr.co/edit/vxtahrYZLcX53p6N?preview)

```
RadioRenderer.prototype.init = function (params) {
this.params = params;
let uniqueId = this.params.node.data.UserId;
let colId = this.params.column.colId;
let colValue = this.params.node.data[colId];

this.eGui = document.createElement('div');

this.eGui.innerHTML = `<div class="row align-items-center">
                               <div class="col-auto">
                                   <div class="form-check form-check-info">
                                       <input style="margin-top:7px !important;" class="form-check-input" value="true" ${
                                         colValue ? 'checked="checked"' : ''
                                       } type="radio" name="${colId}_${uniqueId}" id="${colId}_${uniqueId}_Yes">
                                       <label class="form-check-label" for="${colId}_${uniqueId}_Yes">Yes</label>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-auto" style="margin-left: -10px;">
                                   <div class="form-check form-check-pink">
                                       <input style="margin-top:7px !important;" class="form-check-input" value="false" ${
                                         !colValue ? 'checked="checked"' : ''
                                       } type="radio" name="${colId}_${uniqueId}" id="${colId}_${uniqueId}_No">
                                       <label class="form-check-label" for="${colId}_${uniqueId}_No">No</label>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>`;

this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
this.eGui.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
};
```

[image: plunker ag-grid radio component example]