# Radio Buttons in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to display my data and i have below question:

1.Instead of check boxes i want radio buttons to be displayed when i expand the group and also my grouping is not working as expected.?
Plunkr link for the above grid what i tried so far https://plnkr.co/edit/KahAzPv6QEccaaRKlzCN?p=preview

```
  var gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
             {headerName: "Jobs",field: "job", width: 90,rowGroupIndex: 0 ,hide:true},
            // this tells the grid what values to put into the cell
            //showRowGroup: 'position'
            // this tells the grid what to use to render the cell
           // cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer'

           //{field: 'position', rowGroup: true, hide: true},
           {headerName: "Name", field: "name"}

        ],
        rowData: [
            {position:'Developer',name:'Test1',job:'Position'},
            {position: 'Manager', name:'Test2',job:'Position'},
            {position: 'Musician',job:'Position'},
            {position: 'Manager',name:'Test4',job:'Position'},
            {position: 'Europe',job:'Location'},
            {position: 'Australia',name:'Test4',job:'Location'}
        ],
      /* autoGroupColumnDef:{
       headerName:'',
       cellRendererParams:{
        suppressCount: true,
        checkbox:true
    }
       }*/

       autoGroupColumnDef: {
headerName: "Jobs",
field: "position",
width: 250,
cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
cellRendererParams: {
  checkbox: true
     }
     }
     };
```

Comment: check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52421346/4483102)

Comment: @ un.spike - Is it possible to explain it with a simple example?