# How to update a row in AG-Grid without triggering a refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, ag-grid

My goal is to add a custom radio button to allow the user to select a row. At the moment I have

```
const Cell = (cellProps) => {
   const { data, node, api } = cellProps
   const selectedRow = () => {
    let { isChecked } = data
    let radioButtonLabel = ''
    const newRowData =[]

      api.forEachNode((currNode) => {
        const currRowData = currNode.data
        if (id === currNode.data.id) {
          currRowData.isChecked = true
          radioButtonLabel = currNode.data.name
        }
        newRowData.push(currRowData)
      }) 
    api.setRowData(newRowData)
}}
```

So the problem is that when the user selects a radio button of a row on the bottom of my table, it refreshes the grid (I believe setRowData triggers a refresh) and the user has to scroll to the bottom of the table to see their selection. I want to be able to stop the refresh when the user selects the radio button but not sure how that can be implemented with AG-Grid.

Comment: I found this that might be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52396687/4440629 or if not please can you explain what you want to do differently?

Answer (score 1):

Read through [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update-row-data/) documentation. Specifically the part about providing the row id with `getRowId` (or `getRowNodeId` depending on your version)

It will make the transaction much more efficient without refreshing.

[example](https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=main.js&preview)

If you just want to add a checkbox for selection [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/#checkbox-selection) is the documentation but you seem to need a radio button.

```js
var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: rowDataA,
  rowSelection: 'single',
  animateRows: true,
  getRowId: (params) => params.data.id, // <---
};
```